# How does one go about determining a normalizing factor?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm reading "Introduction to PDEs and Hilbert Space Methods" by Gustafson, and I came across (as I've found elsewhere as well):

> We will use $c_n$ to denote a general Fourier coefficient, that is, if a function $f$ is expanded in terms of a set of eigenfunctions ${\phi_n}$. we will write $f=\sum^\infty_{n=1} c_n \phi_n$ where $c_n=(f,\phi_n)$ in the appropriate inner product of the problem.... $c_n=\int^{\pi}_0 f(x) \phi(x) dx$ where $\phi_n(x)=(2/\pi)^{1/2} sin\; nx$,the $(2/\pi)^{1/2}$ being a normalizing factor.

How does one come up with normalizing factors?

Comment: Often chosen to give $\vert \phi_k\vert ^2 = (\phi_k, \phi_k) = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the projection of a vector $u$ onto the vector $v$ is given by $\left \langle u, \frac{v}{\| v \|} \right \rangle \frac{v}{\| v \|}$ where $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ is the inner product and $\| \cdot \|$ is the induced norm.

Here the inner product is $\langle f,g \rangle = \int_0^\pi f(x) g(x) \, dx$, the induced norm is $\| f \|=\left ( \int_0^\pi f(x)^2 \, dx \right )^{1/2}$. So you normalize by dividing $\sin(nx)$ by $\left ( \int_0^\pi \sin(nx)^2 \, dx \right )^{1/2}$.

Comment: Thank you.  So is your $\langle f,g\rangle$ equivalent to $c_n$? And is your $\Vert f\Vert$ equivalent to $\phi_n(x)$?

Comment: @MichaelTChase $c_n$ is specifically $\langle f,\phi_n \rangle$ meaning that you need to normalize the function you're projecting onto (namely $\sin(nx)$) by dividing by $\| \sin(nx) \|$. That is $\phi_n=\frac{\sin(nx)}{\| \sin(nx) \|}$.

Comment: What about $\Vert f\Vert$?  And what do you mean by "normalize" and "projecting onto".  Is that anything like renormalization and like projecting a vector space on a manifold, respectively?  And I don't see how they got $sin\; nx$ to begin with.

Comment: @MichaelTChase I said what $\| f \|$ is in the answer. Normalize means "make into a unit vector"; if you have a nonzero vector in a space that has a norm, you can make it into a unit vector by dividing it by its norm. Projection means pretty much the same as it means in Euclidean space. The whole thing that you're doing here is taking the function $f$ and projecting it onto each of the functions $\sin(nx)$. The trick is that the functions $\sin(nx)$ are orthogonal, so the projection onto a bunch of them is just the sum of the projections onto each one separately.

Comment: (Cont.) As for where $\sin(nx)$ came from, they are the eigenfunctions of the Laplacian on $[0,\pi]$ which vanish at the boundaries.

Comment: @MichaelTChase If you have no formal background in linear algebra, I would highly suggest backing up and getting that foundation before proceeding in this direction. Many many things in infinite dimensional vector spaces are analogous to the situation in finite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm self-taught and can be sensitive and prideful about my learning Others (you may or may not be) who have "formal" education just can't understand the questions self-learners ask, because we are always pushing the envelope learning things way beyond and then going back to fundamentals.  Thanks for your specific attention and every word you wrote.  Also, questions on stack usually never end for me in clarity because I feel bad about clarifying, then re-clarifying, then asking the same question again.  But this time is the (2/pi)^1/2 makes c_n a unit vector.

Comment: Correction: I see that $c_n$ is being made into a unit vector.  This is all I really need. Ty.

Comment: Not that it matters, but what is confusing to me are not the explanations usage, but meaning, as very many terms have multiple uses across math and physics. So coming to an explanation that can't be confused by different meanings (look up normalize on wiki) was key here.

Comment: The thing that is a unit vector here is $\frac{\sin(nx)}{\sqrt{\pi/2}}$.